# Support for Update, Insert or Delete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Does the Spanner API support DML statements? For example, is the following supported:

```
UPDATE SET foo="bar" WHERE foo="baz"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update as pr mid October 2018:**

Cloud Spanner now **does** support `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` using direct DML:

Blog post about the change:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/develop-and-deploy-apps-more-easily-with-cloud-spanner-and-cloud-bigtable-updates

Docs:
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-tasks

Comment: There's also a `gcloud beta` option `--enable-partitioned-dml` for any updates that are over the 20000 mutation limit.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner does not support INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE DML operations, however you can achieve the same effect by using [read-write transactions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions#read-write_transactions). All mutations to your data must go through the transaction commit method (in either REST or gRPC), which accepts [Mutation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/commit#Mutation) objects.

In your example, you would

1. Start a read-write transaction and execute a SQL statement such as: `SELECT <key> from MyTable where foo="baz"`.
2. Then [commit](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/commit) the transaction and include a list of `Mutation` objects (one for each row you got back from your select) with the `update` property to set all the values to `"bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Spanner itself does not support this, but this JDBC Driver https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc does support it by parsing the supplied SQL and calling the read/write API of Google Cloud Spanner. Have a look at the code in CloudSpannerPreparedStatement to see how it's done. The driver relies on the SQL parsing offered by https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser.

As of version 0.16 and newer of the abovementioned JDBC driver, full DML-statements operating on multiple rows are supported. You can use the driver in combination with a tool like SQuirreL or DBVisualizer in order to send the statements to Cloud Spanner.

Have a look here for some examples: http://www.googlecloudspanner.com/2018/02/data-manipulation-language-with-google.html